# Extract xml from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have following log file from server,I want to extract xml from following string.

```
2:00:11 PM >>Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<HotelML xmlns="http://www.xpegs.com/v2001Q3/HotelML"><Head><Route Destination="TR" Source="00"><Operation Action="Create" App="UltraDirect-d1c1_" AppVer="V1_1" DataPath="/HotelML" StartTime="2013-07-31T08:33:13.223+00:00" Success="true" TotalProcessTime="711"/></Route>............

</HotelML>


3:00:11 PM >>Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<HotelML xmlns="http://www.xpegs.com/v2001Q3/HotelML"><Head><Route Destination="TR" Source="00"><Operation Action="Create" App="UltraDirect-d1c1_" AppVer="V1_1" DataPath="/HotelML" StartTime="2013-07-31T08:33:13.223+00:00" Success="true" TotalProcessTime="711"/></Route>............

</HotelML>

5:00:11 PM >>Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<HotelML xmlns="http://www.xpegs.com/v2001Q3/HotelML"><Head><Route Destination="TR" Source="00"><Operation Action="Create" App="UltraDirect-d1c1_" AppVer="V1_1" DataPath="/HotelML" StartTime="2013-07-31T08:33:13.223+00:00" Success="true" TotalProcessTime="711"/></Route>............

</HotelML>
```

I have written following regular expression for the same but it's matching only the first entry in the string.but i want to return all the xml string as collection.

```
(?<= Response:).*>.*</.*?>
```

Comment: all your exemple log rows starts with "Response: <?xml" and ends with "</HotelML>", is that true for all log rows or just the exemple?

Comment: @Puggan Se:Yes, you are right

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot just assume that the content after 'Response: ' represent an xml document? From there, just run it through a schema to validate and then load it as normal.

Comment: @PugganSe, actually, once you found the "Response" line, it is easy to extract the encoding with a regex... ".*encoding="(.*)".*" and the first group contains the encoding. If you want to be defensive about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach which should leave you with a `List<XDocument>`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var input = File.ReadAllText("text.txt");
        var xmlDocuments = Regex
            .Matches(input, @"([0-9AMP: ]*>>Response: )")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(match =>
                {
                    var currentPosition = match.Index + match.Length;
                    var nextMatch = match.NextMatch();
                    if (nextMatch.Success == true)
                    {
                        return input.Substring(currentPosition,
                            nextMatch.Index - currentPosition);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return input.Substring(currentPosition);
                    }
                })
            .Select(s => XDocument.Parse(s))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why aren't you matching from `<HotelML` to `</HotelML`?

something like:

```
<HotelML .*</HotelML>
```

Or, just go through the file line by line, and whenever you find a line matching

```
^.* PM >>Response:.*$
```

read the following lines as xml until the next matching line...

Comment: If OP can guarantee that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` never changes then this would be a better option than trying to remove `Response`.

Comment: You should use the encoding of the log file, the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` does only say something about the encoding of the message.

Comment: But that information may still be relevant to the program OP is working on.

Comment: It's matching perfectly for single node but for multiple node it's not working